# Why does my program print fffffff0?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand why my program

```
#include<stdio.h>    
void main()  
{  
    printf("%x",-1<<4);  
}
```

prints `fffffff0`.

What is this program doing, and what does the `<<` operator do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<<` operator is the left shift operator; the result of `a<<b` is `a` shifted to the left of `b` bits.

The problem with your code is that you are left-shifting a negative integer, and this results in undefined behavior (although your compiler may place some guarantees on this operation); also, `%x` is used to print in hexadecimal an unsigned integer, and you are feeding to it a signed integer - again undefined behavior.

As for why you are seeing what you are seeing: on 2's complement architectures `-1` is represented as "all ones"; so, on a computer with 32-bit `int` you'll have:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111 = -1 (if interpreted as a signed integer)
```

now, if you shift this to the left of 4 positions, you get:

```
11111111111111111111111111110000
```

The `%x` specifier makes `printf` interprets this stuff as an unsigned integer, which, in hexadecimal notation, is `0xfffffff0`. This is easy to understand, since 4 binary digits equal a single hexadecimal digit; the `1111` groups in binary become `f` in hex, the last `0000` in binary is that last `0` in hex.

Again, all this behavior hereby explained is just the way *your specific compiler* works, as far as the C standard is concerned this is all UB. This is very intentional: historically different platforms had different ways to represent negative numbers, and the shift instructions of various processors have different subtleties, so the "defined behavior" we get for shift operators is more or less the "safe subset" common to most "normal" architectures.

Comment: what do you mean by 32 bit computer here? Please explain as my processor and OS both are 64bit.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "on a computer with a 32-bit `int`".

Answer (score 1):

It means *take bit representation of -1 and shift it to the left 4 times*

This means take

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 = ffffffff
```

And shift:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110000 = fffffff0
```

The `"%x"` format specifier means *print it out in hexadecimal notation*.

Answer (score 0):

It's the left shift binary operator. You're left shifting -1 by 4 bits:

```
  -1    == 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111(2) == FFFFFFFF
-1 << 4 == 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000(2) == FFFFFFF0
```

Answer (score 0):

"%x" means your integer will be displayed in hexadecimal value.

-1 << 4 means that the binary value of "-1" will be shifted of 4 bits

Answer (score 0):

"<<" is left shift operator. -1<<4 means left shifting -1 by 4. Since -1 is 0xffffffff, you will get 0xfffffff0

More can be found in wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation